# iPhone 3.0 MapKit -- providing routing between points

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, mapkit, google-maps

Is it possible to have the MapKit connect defined points using the Google Maps API type routing connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately not — it's part of the SDK agreement that if you do routing, you have to use your own maps, like TomTom and the like have.

Comment: Does this agreement hold over to the Google Maps API in general, or just the MapKit?

Answer (score 2):

> Unfortunately not — it's part of the
>   SDK agreement that if you do routing,
>   you have to use your own maps, like
>   TomTom and the like have.

I don't see this in the 3.1.2 SDK agreement. Reading sections 3.3.7 through 3.3.11, the only restriction I see on routing is one that lines up with Google's terms of use - namely, that you can't claim to provide accurate *real time* routing information. Seems to me like the future is bright for [kishikawakatsumi's MapKit-Route-Directions](http://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/MapKit-Route-Directions).

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  There are some clever solutions with putting a transparent view on top of the map, but officially the MapKit does not support routing.

Answer (score 0):

I guess [this](http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=81) is what marcc meant.