# How can i get the itinerary between two places?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, objective-c-2.0, mapkit

I have an app with a MapView that implements some annotations that i get it from an API and also i tell the MapView to show the current location of the user. so what i want is getting the itinerary from the user location to a place that the user specify?

Comment: i guess you also want to draw the itinerary in the map?

Comment: yes, i want to draw the itinerary

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but you'll need to get the itinerary from an external API (Google works). You can then use MapKit to draw the polylines on top of your map.

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8301673/233944

Answer (score 0):

The native MapKit API doesn't offer routing functionality for 3rd party developers (see here for more details: [iPhone 3.0 MapKit -- providing routing between points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289045/iphone-3-0-mapkit-providing-routing-between-points))

PS, in English the word for this is "routing" or "route planning" - itinerary usually means something else in English, which is probably why you didn't get many answers.